# Limit of cumulative distribution functions is a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Le $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables with a cumulative distribution function $F_{X_n}$. Now of the sequence of function $F_{X_n}$ converge pointwise to a function $F$. Is $F$ itself a cumulative distribution function of some random variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Consider $$F_{X_n}=\begin{cases}
1-\frac{1}{x-n}, & x \geq n+1\\
0,         & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$  The function converges pointwise to zero, which is not a cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 4):

CDFs have some properties, e.g. if $F$ is a CDF then

- $F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$
- $F(x) \to 1$ as $x \to +\infty$
- $F$ is non-decreasing
- $F$ is right-continuous

Can you check if all of them hold in the limit?

**HINT** the second one can fail, so can the first one, if the support decreases correctly

**UPDATE** as suggested in the comments, the last one can fail as well

Comment: And the fourth one can fail too! (+1)

Comment: @SangchulLee up[dated